# Editing values of properties of associated object

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Please help to solve this problem,I am not able to update the values for the properties of an object which is encapsulated inside the list of objects,I have explained below,where exactly am facing the problem with my code.

I have a java bean class(User),which has the List of Objects(ReferenceBean) and values for this list will be accessed by database.And each ReferenceBean Objec has another object(UserAssociate). I need to update the values for the properties of UserAssociate Object.

User class:

```
public class User implements Serializable{

private String userName;    
private String fullName;

private List<ReferenceBean> references;

//corresponding getter,setter methods.
}
```

ReferenceBean class:

```
public class ReferenceBean implements Serializable{

boolean add;
boolean modify;
boolean delete;
UserAssociate userAssociate;

 //corresponding getter,setter methods.
}
```

UserAssociate class:

```
public class UserAssociate implements Serializable {

int moduleCode;
boolean add;
boolean modify;
boolean delete;
//corresponding getter,setter methods.
}
```

Below is my jsp page.I am using SpringMVC and in jsp page I have setted modelAttribute="user" to read its values from the controller layer.
Here am successfully getting the values from the DB but am not able to update the values(checkboxes) for the properties of UserAssociate.(Tried using  with path attribute also but couldnt achieve).

```
        <tr><td>
            Full Name<form:input path="fullName" />
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
            User Name<form:input path="userName" />
        </td></tr>

        <table class="tableNew">
            <tr>
                <td><b> Add </b></td>
                <td><b>Modify</b></td>
                <td><b>Delete </b></td>
            </tr>

        <c:forEach var="ref" items="${user.references}">
            <tr>
            <td><c:if test="${ref.isAdd()}">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${ref.userAssociate.isAdd()}">
                     <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                     <input type="checkbox" />
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose></c:if></td>

            <td><c:if test="${ref.isModify()}">
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${ref.userAssociate.isModify()}">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                </c:when>
                <c:otherwise>
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </c:otherwise>
            </c:choose></c:if></td>

            <td><c:if test="${ref.isDelete()}">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${ref.userAssociate.isDelete()}">
                        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose></c:if></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
     </table>
```